# Erro em ordenar números positivos e negativos Jasvascript

Tags: javascript, order

Tenho um array com vários números, esses números são positivos, negativos e com decimal também:

```
var array = [365, -1.304, -17.803, -3.529, -3.602, -2.942, -2.074, -115]
```

Preciso ordenar esse array de forma do **MENOR** para o **MAIOR**. O resultado que era de se esperar é:

```
[-17.803, -3.602, -3.529, -2.942, -2.074, -1.304, -115, 365]
```

Mas ao invés disso está saindo isso:

```
[-115, -17.803, -3.602, -3.529, -2.942, -2.074, -1.304, 365]
```

O código que estou usando para ordenar:

```
GraphOne[Regional].sort(function(a,b){return a > b});
```

Comment: @leofontes, mas -17.803 é 17 mil. Então 17 mil está mais longe do 0 do que -115

Comment: Cara, você tá usando `.`. Isso é separador decimal

Comment: @AlissonAcioli sim eu tinha lido na convenção inglesa então fazia sentido meu comentário, mas você tá pensando em português.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa tirar o . dos números, o Javascript usa a convenção inglesa no qual o . é a nossa ,

No caso, pra eles 1.100 = um virgula um, enquanto pra nós seria mil e cem.

```
var array = [365, -1304, -17803, -3529, -3602, -2942, -2074, -115];

console.log(array);

array.sort(function(a,b){return a > b});

console.log(array);
```

Dá o resultado correto. Espero que tenha ficado clara a confusão que estava ocorrendo.

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que remover os pontos decimais de todos os valores do array para poder considerá-lo como um inteiro. Para isso voce pode usar o [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), dentro da função convertendo cada número em string, trocar `.` por vazio, e então converter para número novamente.

```js
var array = [365, -1.304, -17.803, -3.529, -3.602, -2.942, -2.074, -115].map(function(x) {
  x += '';
  return Number(x.replace('.', ''));
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

console.log(array);
```